# Updating State Context API, how to stop state from overwriting the current value in the reducer function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this reducer case, problem is it overwrite the the passed id instead of adding to the existing array of id. could you please explain that general idea behind copying the sate and where should I use the (...state) spread operator behind the item it self or after the item when the change is happening, to me this is the hardest part to grasp when it comes to state management ?

```js
   case ADD_ITEM:
      return   {
        ...state, 
          item : {
          ...state.item,
          [action.infoId]: [{ id : action.id}]
          }
        };
```

Comment: So you want to add another `action.id` into the array inside your item?

Comment: yes... not one but as many I want.

Comment: See if my answer works for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### **You will  need to spread your `item[action.infoID]` too:**

**Change to:**

```
case ADD_ITEM:
  return   {
    ...state, 
      item : {
      ...state.item,
      [action.infoId]: [...state.item[action.infoId], action.id]
      }
    };
```

---

The spread operator is basically spreading every item from your object/array

From [mozilla deffinition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

```js
function sum(x, y, z) {
  return x + y + z;
}

const numbers = [1, 2, 3];

console.log(sum(...numbers));
// expected output: 6

console.log(sum.apply(null, numbers));
// expected output: 6
```